# Mediawiki table: "efficiently" applying different alignment for different column

Tags: css, html-table, mediawiki

How can I efficiently center-align some columns while left-align others?

I want to do something like this.

```
-------------------------
|     A      |B         |
-------------------------
|     C      |D         |
-------------------------
```

This code makes all columns centered.

```
{| class="wikitable" style="text-align: center;"
|-
! Header 1
! Header 2
|-
| A
| B
|-
| C
| D
|}
```

And I know the following code does what I want.

```
{| class="wikitable"
|-
! Header 1
! Header 2
|-
| style="text-align: center;" | A
| B
|-
| style="text-align: center;" | C
| D
|}
```

But since I need to make a quite lenghty table, this is tedious.

Is there any code that will center-align only the 1st column using a very simple one line of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you disabled it in `LocalSettings.php`, you can use the page `MediaWiki:Common.css` to add extra stylesheets to all pages. Just do what you need there, using plain CSS. E.g:

```
.myTableClass td {
    text-align: left;
}

.myTableClass td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

...and then add that class to your tables

```
{| class="wikitable myTableClass"
|-
| A
| B
|-
| C
| D
|}
```

Comment: What should be the class for my case (some column center-align, other columns left-align)?

Comment: The example above is for making the first column in each row center aligned, and the rest left aligned!

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer, while correct, can be tedious to implement generally, as you need to create a distinct CSS class for every combination of column position and text alignment that you need.

An alternative approach for one-offs is to embed CSS directly into the wiki page. On wikis that are only edited by trusted users, you can enable [`$wgRawHtml`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml). On others, you can use an extension such as [`Extension:CSS`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CSS). If you have multiple tables, you can restrict the styling to each table by using `#id` selectors.

```
<html>   <!-- assumes $wgRawHtml = true; safer alternatives exist -->
    <style>
        table#accounts tr td:nth-child(3),
        table#accounts tr td:nth-child(4) 
        { 
            text-align: right; 
        }
    </style>
</html>
{| class="wikitable" id="accounts"
! Account Number !! Account Name !! Source Balance !! Target Balance
|-
| 1234 || UK Savings     ||    402.00 ||    323.21
|-
| 5432 || Car Fund       || 12,943.00 || 23,433.21
|-
| 6789 || Other Expenses ||      4.21 ||      6.21
|}
```

**Edit**: On second thoughts, going with a global approach does result in cleaner syntax within the wiki pages, especially if you have many tables with columns to align. I've created CSS classes for each alignment in the [`MediaWiki:Common.css`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css) page:

```
table.col-1-center td:nth-child(1) { text-align: center; }
table.col-2-center td:nth-child(2) { text-align: center; }
table.col-3-center td:nth-child(3) { text-align: center; }
table.col-4-center td:nth-child(4) { text-align: center; }
table.col-5-center td:nth-child(5) { text-align: center; }
table.col-6-center td:nth-child(6) { text-align: center; }
table.col-7-center td:nth-child(7) { text-align: center; }
table.col-8-center td:nth-child(8) { text-align: center; }
table.col-9-center td:nth-child(9) { text-align: center; }

table.col-1-right td:nth-child(1) { text-align: right; }
table.col-2-right td:nth-child(2) { text-align: right; }
table.col-3-right td:nth-child(3) { text-align: right; }
table.col-4-right td:nth-child(4) { text-align: right; }
table.col-5-right td:nth-child(5) { text-align: right; }
table.col-6-right td:nth-child(6) { text-align: right; }
table.col-7-right td:nth-child(7) { text-align: right; }
table.col-8-right td:nth-child(8) { text-align: right; }
table.col-9-right td:nth-child(9) { text-align: right; }
```

Then, within your wiki pages, you can simply reference the CSS class:

```
{| class="wikitable col-3-right col-4-right"
! Account Number !! Account Name !! Source Balance !! Target Balance
|-
| 1234 || UK Savings     ||    402.00 ||    323.21
|-
| 5432 || Car Fund       || 12,943.00 || 23,433.21
|-
| 6789 || Other Expenses ||      4.21 ||      6.21
|}
```

The added advantage of this approach is that you don't need to enable `$wgRawHtml` or install extensions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I'm now (happily) using it on my site https://beijerterm.com/.